# How do we predict 1 single Datapoint with LogisticRegression

Tags: nlp, logistic-regression

I have been working on an NLP problem (text classification).

I first preprocessed the text, then trained a model on that data (After Tfidf)

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(ref_red, uniqueOutput...)

clf = LogisticRegression(C = 0.9, penalty = 'l1', solver = 'liblinear') # Grid Search    
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print(accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))
```

Now, I want to try and test the model on a single datapoint (ML inference).
How do pass a single datapt to predict function?

Please let me know.

Comment: Does the answer provide you with any help? Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing to keep in mind is dimension agreement between `Training` and `Inference` data.

```
X, y = make_classification()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
dim = X_train.shape[-1]
clf = LogisticRegression(C = 0.9, penalty = 'l1', solver = 'liblinear') # Grid Search    
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
sample_count = 1
clf.predict(np.random.rand(sample_count, dim))
```